# ThemeSwitcher : Null check operator used on a null value, when want to switch app theme between light and dark theme

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, flutter-dependencies

When i click on the button to change the app theme, this error shows up :

```
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture: 
Null check operator used on a null value
```

This is my code, and I'm using ThemeSwitcher package :

```
 AppBar buildAppBar(BuildContext context, bool isEdit) {
  final icon = CupertinoIcons.moon_stars;
  final isDarkMode = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;

  return AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (isEdit == true) Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    actions: [
      ThemeSwitcher(
        clipper: ThemeSwitcherBoxClipper(),
        builder: (context) => IconButton(
          icon: Icon(icon),
          // Button to change theme
          onPressed: () {
            final theme = isDarkMode ? Themes.lightTheme : Themes.darkTheme;

            // originally, there is a '!' on the switcher context below, but it says switcher context can never be null.
            final switcher = ThemeSwitcher.of(context);

            switcher.changeTheme(theme: theme, isReversed: false); //this is the code that the error pointed.
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

So how can I solve this error? I have this code from watching a tutorial from youtube and i wrote exactly the same code.

Comment: Can you include the package link

Comment: I used animated_theme_switcher: ^2.0.6. But it's solved now. turns out that i got the ThemeProvider in my main.dart from a wrong package. I suppose to chose from the animated theme switcher, but instead i chose ThemeProvider from ThemeProvider Package.

Answer (score 0):

refer to readme of [animated_theme_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher)

You must declare **ThemeProvider** above your **MaterialApp** to make ThemeSwitcher access from below widget level

So make sure you do this first

```
ThemeProvider(
      initTheme: initTheme,
      builder: (context, myTheme) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: myTheme,
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }),
    ),
```

Where initTheme is default theme of application or dependent on system theme like this

```
 final isPlatformDark =
        WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    final initTheme = isPlatformDark ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light();
```

see [this](https://github.com/kherel/animated_theme_switcher/blob/master/example/lib/theme_config.dart) example on how edit default Theme

Comment: Thank you man. it turn out that i got the ThemeProvider from a wrong package. I suppose to chose from the animated theme switcher, but instead i chose ThemeProvider from ThemeProvider Package.

Comment: your wlc,happy coding @EnricoAntonio